# SDL-Mixer audio stops upon starting Reactive-Banana input loop

Tags: multithreading, haskell, sdl, reactive-banana, sdl-mixer

I've been working on a game that uses multiple audio tracks whose volumes are adjusted in realtime based on mouse motion. I'm using SDl-Mixer for audio, and Reactive-Banana for the game in general. The problem is that the tracks, which have all been started at the beginning, stop playing when the input-loop starts. The cause may be something else, but I wonder if there's some strange interaction between SDL and Reactive-Banana that I don't understand. I've been trying to puzzle this out for a while, but it might just be something simple that I've overlooked. Thanks in advance. Here's the code for a simple test:

```
import Reactive.Banana
import Graphics.UI.SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer
import Control.Monad

musicdir = "/home/silas/code/haskell/river/audio/"

testNet :: AddHandler (Int,Int,[MouseButton]) -> NetworkDescription t ()
testNet mouseHdlr = do
  eMouse <- fromAddHandler mouseHdlr
  reactimate $ (putStrLn . show) <$> eMouse

main = withInit [InitEverything] $ do
         setVideoMode 100 100 32 [SWSurface]
         openAudio defaultFrequency AudioS16Sys 1 1024
         allocateChannels 1
         chunk <- loadWAV $ musicdir ++ "guitar1" ++ ".ogg"
         playChannel 0 chunk (-1)
         (mouseHdlr, mouseAction) <- newAddHandler
         net <- compile $ testNet mouseHdlr
         actuate net
         forever $ getMouseState >>= mouseAction
```

Edit: The problem doesn't seem to lie in Reactive Banana necessarily. Any sort of 'forever' loop causes the audio to stop.

Comment: What happens when you remove reactive-banana from the picture by replacing the last line with `forever $ getMouseState  >>= print`?

Comment: Same result. I'm pretty sure reactive-banana isn't the problem, at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be your problem, but when I had a similar issue it was that the Garbage Collector could not tell that I was still using the SDL audio chunk (because only SDL was using it) and free'd the RAM out from under SDL.  To solve this you not only have to make sure that the item is in scope for the entire time SDL will be using it, but that your Haskell code actually makes use of it in some way (so that the optimiser doesn't change things on you).  Calls like `touchForeignPtr` are very useful for this.

Comment: Yes! The garbage collection was my problem. Thank you. Repeatedly calling `touchForeignPtr` prevented the chunk from being deleted by the garbage collector, and the audio continued.

Comment: This seems to be a deficit in the SDL library bindings, then.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Uhh... maybe?  How would you build them so that the GC knows to keep something in scope?  I guess you could do something like Hipmunk does and close over a map of everything... or something.  To be fair, the SDL bindings are really thin, especially the bindings to -Mixer and -Gfx

Comment: Well, on the Haskell side, the GC is correct to free the audio data as it is no longer used there. Calling `touchForeignPtr ` works, but it's not the right solution. Instead, the SDL side should be responsible for keeping the data alive and for freeing it again.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to either SDL or reactive-banana.  Issues like that are often fixed by compiling with the `-threaded` compiler flag.  If this is a Cabal project, add

```
GHC-Options: -W -threaded
```

to your `Executable` section.

Comment: Tried it, didn't seem to help. In fact, the audio didn't start at all. Does this have to do with the fact that the FFI spawns its own thread? I'm wondering if I need to explicitly fork a thread for SDL. I'm really inexperienced with FFI in haskell, so I might have the wrong idea.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if you use `-threaded`, then the audio will not start at all, but if you don't use `-threaded`, then it will at least start? If so, then this is an indication that SDL doesn't work well with concurrency. (Which is probably unsurprising.)

Comment: SDL is designed to work with concurrency (it has a thread library in it), but there are of course some rules.  Most SDL calls can only be made from the thread where `SDL.init` was initially called, but having other threads around certainly won't cause an issue :)

Comment: @Apfelmus: I'm actually not using any concurrency at this point (not to my knowledge), but yeah, that's what happened.