# Using Gloss to run a simulation while using SDL to play a sound

Tags: haskell, audio, sdl

I have a simulation that's tied to data gleaned from a sound file.  I would like to run the simulation and play the sound file at the same time to see how well my data matches up.

The problem is that I seem to be unable to play a sound via SDL.Mixer and run a Gloss simulation at the same time.  Both of these functions work fine on their own.

The window for the simulation gets created, but nothing is drawn and the wav file plays.  Could this be that the data to make the model for the simulation (`onsets`) is extremely computationally expensive?  It doesn't seem to get evaluated at all.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Float
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Control.Monad

import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Simulate
import Graphics.Gloss.Data.Color

import qualified Sound.File.Sndfile as Snd
import qualified Sound.File.Sndfile.Buffer.Vector as B
import qualified Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import qualified Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer as Mix

--My own libraries
import Sound.Analysis.Spectrum
import Sound.Analysis.SpectralFlux
import Sound.Analysis.Onset
import Sound.Data.Buffers

--(TimeElapsed, ToDraw, ToBeDrawn)
type Time = Float
type DrawableOnsets = (Time, Onset, OnsetStream)

main = do
    --bs holds our BufferS
    (info, Just (bs :: B.Buffer Double)) <- Snd.readFile "./downtheroad.wav"
    --Convert to an unboxed array
    let b = sterilize bs

    --Grab all of the sound file
    let ct = (truncate $ (fromIntegral $ Snd.frames info)/2048)
    let i = StreamInfo 1024 44100 2

    let b' = sampleRawPCM 0 ct (i, b)
    let s = pcmStream b'

    --Very expensive computations
    let freqs   = freqStream s --Get frequency bins
    let fluxes  = fluxStream freqs --Get spectral flux
    let onsets = onset fluxes --Get onsets based on spectral flux

    let onsetModel = makeModel onsets

    let dispWin = InWindow "Onset Test" (1440, 300) (0,0)

    forkIO playSound
    simulate dispWin white 45 onsetModel drawOnsets stepWorld

    print "done"

playSound = do
    SDL.init [SDL.InitAudio]
    result <- Mix.openAudio 44100 Mix.AudioS16LSB 2 4096
    toPlay <- Mix.loadWAV "./downtheroad.wav"
    ch1 <- Mix.playChannel (-1) toPlay 0
    fix $ \loop -> do
        SDL.delay 50
        stillPlaying <- Mix.numChannelsPlaying
        when (stillPlaying /= 0) loop



makeModel :: OnsetStream -> DrawableOnsets
makeModel (i, os) = (0.0, Onset 0 0.0, (i, os))

drawOnsets :: DrawableOnsets -> Picture
drawOnsets (t, o, os) = translate x 50 $ color red $ circleSolid rad
    where   rad = (double2Float $ power o)*0.01
            x   = (fromIntegral $ frame o)

stepWorld :: ViewPort -> Float -> DrawableOnsets -> DrawableOnsets
stepWorld vp t' (t, o, (i, os)) = (elapsed, o', (i, os'))
    where   o'  | elapsed > nextTime = head os
                | otherwise          = o

            os' | (elapsed > nextTime) = tail os
                | otherwise          = os

            elapsed = t+t'*1000
            interval = (fromIntegral $ sampleRate i)/(fromIntegral $ fftWindow i)
            nextTime = (fromIntegral $ frame o) * 86
```

I've tried a few things such as using `evaluate` in the `Control.Exception` package as such.

```
makeModel :: DrawableOnsets -> IO DrawableOnsets
makeModel  (i, os) = do evaluate (0.0, Onset 0 0.0, os)
```

To try and force the evaluation of the expensive computations, but it seems to have no effect.  The same goes for adding a bang pattern to `makeModel` and in the `let` declarations in `main`.

```
...
let !freqs = freqStream s
let !fluxes = fluxStream freqs
...

makeModel (i, !os) = (0.0, Onset 0 0.0, os)
```

Futhermore, if I try to forkIO both `playSound` and `simulate` my program simply terminates without playing a sound or the simulation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not self-contained, so I stripped it down to `forkIO playSound` followed by `Gloss.display` of static picture, and experienced the same problem: sound is playing but nothing is displayed until it stops.

I found out that [SDL-mixer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL-mixer/0.6.1/doc/html/src/Graphics-UI-SDL-Mixer-Channels.html) uses only `unsafe` foreign functions which are not preemptible. So I replaced `SDL.delay 50` (which blocks current OS thread for the entire duration) with `threadDelay 50000` to give the scheduler chance to do its work, and changed `forkIO` to `forkOS` to make sure that all FFI calls to SDL are issued from the same OS thread (generally a good idea when dealing with stateful libraries). Now the picture appears immediately, but sound ends abruptly after a fraction of second.

Then I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448757/200540) suggesting that audio chunk could be freed by Haskell GC while it is still playing. After inserting `touchForeignPtr toPlay` before `threadDelay` everything works as expected.

```
playSound = do
    SDL.init [SDL.InitAudio]
    result <- Mix.openAudio 44100 Mix.AudioS16LSB 2 4096
    toPlay <- Mix.loadWAV "./sound.wav"
    ch1 <- Mix.playChannel (-1) toPlay 0
    fix $ \loop -> do
        touchForeignPtr toPlay
        threadDelay 50000
        stillPlaying <- Mix.numChannelsPlaying
        when (stillPlaying /= 0) loop
```

Of course, make sure that you compile with threaded RTS (`-threaded` GHC option). Computationally intensive simulation may introduce additional problems, I am eager to know how it works out for you.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you so much! I did have some problems with it starting more than one stream of sound and before the Gloss simulation, but that was easily fixed. By using simulateIO and moving the forkOS to the simulateIO loop and running a test that only fired the very first time simulateIO was called I was able to have everything timed correctly.